# wpf dependency property show a dialog to select the value

Tags: wpf, wcf

I have created a custom control with new dependency property (TagToSet) of type MyTag(id, name, value).
After adding this control to my window design, and going to the properties to set the value of the new dependency property. Here I want to open a dialog to select the Tag that I want (like the case when the dependency property is collection).
note: the Tag property is not a collection, and the required dialog should connect to a WCF service to list the available tag.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the start key Microsoft.Windows.Design.PropertyEditing
for those who are trying to do like me read this
[article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546930.aspx)